# Can $[A\otimes I_m,B]=0$ for all $A$ imply $B=I_n\otimes C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, kronecker-product

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $I_m$ is an $m-$dimensional identity matrix. If $[A\otimes I_m,B]=0$ for all $A$ where $\otimes$ is Kronecker product, does it imply $B$ must be of form $B=I_n\otimes C$ where $C$ is an $m\times m$ matrix? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: Is the bracket for commutator ?

Comment: Yes @dezdichado